# Force java jar to not use classpath packages on EMR

Tags: java, scala, sbt, classpath, amazon-emr

I am trying to run a fat jar through `spark-submit` on EMR. I am running into a problem related to package dependencies. This project depends on `google adwords` library which I have included in `build.sbt`. The problem is that `google adwords` library internally depends on a package called `commons-configuration` version 1.10 but when I run this jar on EMR through `spark-submit` which runs via `yarn scheduler` the version 1.6 of this package (`commons-configuration`) is used as it is part of the CLASSPATH on the EMR cluster. I get the following error

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.configuration.MapConfiguration`

I have tried passing the dependency jar explicitly using option `--jars` of `spark-submit`

```
spark-submit --name my-awesome-spark-job --deploy-mode cluster --class package.path.to.my.Main --jars s3://jar-bucket/jars/commons-configuration-1.10.jar s3://code-bucket/jars/spark-code.jar
```

Doing this still gives me the same error as the package of older version from CLASSPATH is being used not matter what.
I would like to force my jar to include the dependency inside the fat jar and use them explicitly for certain libraries e.g `google adwords` library here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to shade the dependencies that you are using and that have an older version available on cluster.

What do you use to build the jar? I've used this strategy with sbt
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading

But there is also a shade plugin for maven: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: I am using `sbt-assembly` for building the jar. I tried shading the google library using `ShadeRule.rename("com.google.**" -> "shade.com.google.@1").inAll` but the thing is this library internally depends on some other library which have older version on the cluster. So this didn't help me.

Comment: Your solution worked, I shaded `commons-configuration` library and everything works like a charm. Thanks a ton!
I added the following line
```ShadeRule.rename("org.apache.commons.configuration.**" -> "shade.org.apache.commons.configuration.@1").inAll```